# Do partial derivatives exist? If so, are they equal?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y) = xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ when $x^2+y^2\ne0$ and $f(x,y) = 0$ otherwise. Is $f^{''}_{xy}(0,0)=f^{''}_{yx}(0,0)$ true?

I have shown that neither $f^{'}_{x}(0,0)$ nor $f^{'}_{y}(0,0)$ exist. Does this mean that both $f^{''}_{xy}(0,0)$ and $f^{''}_{yx}(0,0)$ do not exist and the above statement is not true?

Could you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: I think that $f_x'(0,0)$ does exist.

Comment: $f'_x(0,0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x}$ is ...

Comment: Could you prove it? @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Yes, I think the limit as provided by @mfl is quite an easy one...

Comment: Okay, I found that the paritial derivatives at (0, 0) are equal to 0. Now how to compute second degree derivatives at (0, 0)? @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Right then, $$f_{x,y}''(0,0)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f'_x(0,y)-f'_x(0,0)}y,$$ if that exists; so what is that?

Comment: OK, I got it@LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved the problem. $f^{''}_{xy}(0,0)=-1$ and $f^{''}_{yx}(0,0)=1$

Answer (score 1):

Given $f(x,y)=xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$, the first-order partial derivatives at $x^2+y^2\neq 0$ are given by

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(xy-\frac{2xy^3}{x^2+y^2})=y+2y^3\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2},$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(-xy+\frac{2x^3y}{x^2+y^2})=-x+2x^3\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}.$$

The partial derivatives at $x=y=0$ are $0$. Then the second-order mixed partial derivatives at $x=y=0$ are calculated using

$$\left.\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}\right|_{(0,0)}=\lim_{\Delta y\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\Delta y}\left(\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{(0,\Delta y)}-\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{(0,0)}\right)=1,$$
$$\left.\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}\right|_{(0,0)}=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\Delta x}\left(\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{(\Delta x,0)}-\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{(0,0)}\right)=-1.$$
The mixed derivatives are not equal because the function $f(x,y)=xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ is singular at $x=y=0$.